# Socket Stream writing

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization

The language is Java and the question : having some application listening on a port, and this application is multithreaded, having threads kept in a ThreadLocals Set.Can  I by opening a socket to stream and transfer a file, can I open the socket and deliver it to the specific thread ? The application already transfers specific serializable objects of X-interface between sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am agree with Peter. But if you stepped back, validated your design and decided that you really need this I think you can do it as following.

You should add to your protocol any indication of thread. Let's say that you call your threads 1, 2, 3 etc. So, each command being sent from client should contain the thread ID it is dedicated to. The listening thread should extract this value and submit task to specific thread. I have no idea whether you can do it using existing thread pools you you need your own. But no worries: if your thread pool is simple (i.e. is not changing number of threads dynamically etc) it is just a 10 code lines to write your own thread pool: create list of threads `List<Thread>`, and write loop that fills it: `threads.add(new Thread())`.

Each thread should wait on its own queue of `Runnable`s. When new task arrives to Thread #n, just create runnable and put it into corresponding queue.

Comment: just wanted to add ages after, that because of this idea, I made then a table where I tracked thread communication between client/server..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to have a worker thread is to use a ExecutorService which is single threaded (or a pool if you wish) You can then give it tasks with

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executor.execute(new Runnable() { ... });

executor.shutdown();
```

Not sure why you would keep Threads in ThreadLocal variables.  Perhaps it is time to take a step back from your design and ask yourself if you can do this in a simpler way.